# Limiting the UL traffic on a Windows 7 PC

Tags: windows, bandwidth, traffic, network-traffic

I have multiple users at home. One main PC which is connected via a cable, and other Wireless users. When a user tries to Upload something (For example, Youtube, Facebook, etc), the entire bandwidth is used and no one can actually do something.

I am looking for a software to limit the UL for each **Windows** PC (I am planning to install it on the PC itself). It doesn't have to be a secret, just a plain program.

The router that I have is from my ISP, and QOS is disabled on it (I can't enable it, and since it's "not my property" I can't really hack it).

Would appreciate your help if you know this kind of a program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lite version of NetLimiter [(feature matrix here)](http://www.netlimiter.com/featurelistnl3.php) should be enough for your needs.

Comment: Thank you, I will surely try it.